# Combine Google Places & my DB Places Adapter in a list view in Android

Tags: android, listview, adapter, google-places-api, autosuggest

I have two adapters -
1. Google places adapter &
2. My local Database places adapter.

I want to combine these two adapters in a single adapter in order to show the suggestions in a single list view. Implementing two separate adapters with two different listviews work fine. But the top listview is becoming only one row which is scrollable. But I want the total results of the two listviews to be in a single scroll. I have put the two list views inside a scrollview, but it has the same issue. The code for the two adapters are as follows.

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Google Places Autocomplete";
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
    private static final String API_KEY = "XYZ";
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;
    private ArrayList<String> descriptionList = null;
    private ArrayList<String> descriptionList1 = null;
    private ArrayList<String> descriptionList2 = null;
    private Context context = null;

    public ArrayList<String> placeid = null;;

    public PlacesAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (resultList != null)
            return resultList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    public String getPlaceId(int index) {
        return placeid.get(index);
    }


    public ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:in");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            Log.d("yo", jsonResults.toString());
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            placeid = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            descriptionList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            descriptionList1 = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            descriptionList2 = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
                String place = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
                placeid.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id"));
                String[] placeindex = place.split(",");
                descriptionList.add(placeindex[0]);
                descriptionList1.add(placeindex[1]);
                descriptionList2.add(placeindex[2]);

            }
         //   saveArray(resultList.toArray(new String[resultList.size()]), "predictionsArray", getContext());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }catch (IllegalStateException exp){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", exp);
        }
        return descriptionList;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                  //  setImageVisibility();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tLocation;
        TextView tLocationInfo;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        View vix = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            if (vix == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_stopinfo, null);
            }

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tLocation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_name);
            holder.tLocationInfo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_info);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try{
            String locationName = descriptionList.get(position).replace(","," ");
            String placeName = (descriptionList1.get(position).replace(" ", "")+", "+
                    descriptionList2.get(position).replace(" ", ""));

            if (locationName != null) {
                holder.tLocation.setText(locationName);
                if (placeName != null) {
                    holder.tLocationInfo.setText(placeName);
                } else {
                    holder.tLocationInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My Local Database Adapter -

```
public class BusStopAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BusStops>
{

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<BusStops> items;

    public BusStopAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<BusStops> items, int layout) {
        super(context, layout, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }


    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tLocation;
        TextView tLocationInfo;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        View vix = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            if (vix == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_stopinfo, null);
            }

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tLocation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_name);
            holder.tLocationInfo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_info);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        BusStops stopObject = items.get(position);

        if (stopObject != null)
        {
            holder.tLocation.setText(stopObject.getStopName());
            if (stopObject.getStopInfo() != null && stopObject.getStopInfo().length() > 0) {
                holder.tLocationInfo.setText(stopObject.getStopInfo());
            } else {
                holder.tLocationInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public BusStops getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }
}
```

This is how I am implementing the Text Change Listener -

```
myAdapter = new PlacesAdapter(LocationListActivity.this,R.layout.row_stopinfo);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);

location.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        Utils.setDynamicHeight(listView);
        busStopList = newBusList(s);
        setAdapter();
        busStopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     //   Utils.setDynamicHeight(mListView);

      //  Utils.setDynamicHeight(mListView);
     //   mListView.setAdapter(busStopAdapter);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: how are you creating `BusStopAdapter`? how do you populate initial list of items? is it sqlite where the data is taken from?

Comment: I am using it like this -  busStopAdapter = new BusStopAdapter(LocationListActivity.this,busStopList,R.layout.row_stopinfo);
        mListView.setAdapter(busStopAdapter);
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

Comment: so use `CursorAdapter`, in most cases `SimpleCursorAdapter` is a good choice

Comment: Ok. I will add my two adapter usages in the main activity. Please check it out.

Comment: `two adapter` ? what `two adapter`?

Comment: I am initializing google places adapter and my local db adapter to populate places suggestions from a single edit text.

Comment: Is there a way to merge these two adapters in a single adapter and show in a single listview?

Comment: sure you can merge two adapters but it would be better to merge two data sets, in your case: `MergeCursor`

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a small view of how to implement Merge cursor in my case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you dont have to implement anything: just create a new `MergeCursor` based on two other `Cursor`s